# CakePHP 3.x - How to pass pagination configuration directly instead of using the controller `$paginate` property?

Tags: cakephp, configuration, pagination, cakephp-3.x

The below code works:

```
// Somewhere in the Controller
public $paginate = [ 'maxLimit'=>2 ];
// In the method:
$query=$this->Model->find('all')->where(....);
$this->set('results',$this->paginate($query));
```

However, I do not want to specify $paginate as public in the controller. I would rather not specify it at all. I tried to move maxLimit setting to the method but I'm doing it incorrectly. How can I change the below code?

```
$query=$this->Model->find('all')->where(....);
$this->set('results',$this->paginate($query, ['maxLimit'=>2]));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [**`Controller::paginate()`**](http://api.cakephp.org/3.2/class-Cake.Controller.Controller.html#_paginate) method doesn't take a second argument. What you are looking for is the `paginate()` method of the Paginator component, which is accessible in your controller via the `$this->Paginator` property.

```
$this->Paginator->paginate($query, ['maxLimit' => 2])
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Controller > Components > Pagination > Using the Paginator Directly](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/pagination.html#using-the-paginator-directly)**
- **[API > \Cake\Controller\Component\Paginator::paginate()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.2/class-Cake.Controller.Component.PaginatorComponent.html#_paginate)**

Comment: You know all answers to my questions :) thank you for sharing your knowledge.