# Using the paginator directly is not recognising the configuration

Tags: cakephp

CakePHP Version: 4.0.1

**Introduction**

I have 2 methods that both use the index view, *index* and *search*. On index the column can be selected from a select list and a value can be inputted via an input form control enabling a search by column and value. This data is sent via GET to the search method where empty values are checked and the query is executed and the index view is rendered.

In the later 3x versions with the below configuration the index view had the sort on the selected column which is what it is meant to do.

IE: Index view has due_date sorted on the initial load and I select task_name then submit the form to the search method. The task_name has the sort when the view is rendered.

---

**TASKS CONTROLLER**

**Public pagination property:**

```
public $paginate = [
    'sortWhitelist' => [
       'Tasks.due_date',
       'Tasks.task_name',
       'Tasks.type',
       'Tasks.priority',
       'Tasks.related_to_name',
       'Contacts.first_name',
       'Contacts.last_name',
       'Accounts.account_name',
       'Tasks.task_desc'
    ]
];
```

**Search Method**

I initialise the data received from the index method and apply the config to the pagination property and send the query object to the view.

```
$this->setPage('');
$this->setSort($this->request->getQuery('column'));
$this->setDirection('asc');

// Validation of the page, sort, direction and limit is done here.
// IE: The $this->getSort() must be a string and not be numeric and has a strlen check
// and the $this->getDirection() can only be a string with values 'asc' or 'desc' etc. 

if (!empty($this->getPage())) {
    $this->paginate['page'] = $this->getPage();
}
$this->paginate['sort'] = $this->getSort();
$this->paginate['direction'] = $this->getDirection();
$this->paginate['limit'] = $this->getLimit();

debug($this->paginate);

$tasks = $this->paginate($query);
$this->set(compact('tasks'));
```

**The result of debug is:**

```
[
    'sortWhitelist' => [
        (int) 0 => 'Tasks.due_date',
        (int) 1 => 'Tasks.task_name',
        (int) 2 => 'Tasks.type',
        (int) 3 => 'Tasks.priority',
        (int) 4 => 'Tasks.related_to_name',
        (int) 5 => 'Contacts.first_name',
        (int) 6 => 'Contacts.last_name',
        (int) 7 => 'Accounts.account_name',
        (int) 8 => 'Tasks.task_desc'
    ],
    'sort' => 'Tasks.task_name',
    'direction' => 'asc',
    'limit' => (int) 25
 ]
```

**Result**
The sort is on the task_name.

---

A couple of months ago I upgraded to 4 and have just revisted this functionality to find the sort is on the column that was present on index and not the column that was selected. I tried the below to fix the problem:

I referenced [this](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/controllers/components/pagination.html#using-the-paginatorcomponent-directly) information in the cookbook. And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38903701/cakephp-3-x-how-to-pass-pagination-configuration-directly-instead-of-using-the) from SO.

```
$config = $this->paginate = [
    'page' => $this->getPage(),
    'sort' => $this->getSort(),
    'direction' => $this->getDirection(),
    'limit' => $this->getLimit()
];

debug($config);

$tasks = $this->Paginator->paginate($query, $config);

debug($this->Paginator);

$this->set(compact('tasks'));
```

**The result of debug $config is:**

```
[
    'page' => '',
    'sort' => 'Tasks.task_name',
    'direction' => 'asc',
    'limit' => (int) 25
]
```

**The result of debug $this->Paginator is:**

```
object(Cake\Controller\Component\PaginatorComponent) {

    'components' => [],
    'implementedEvents' => [],
    '_config' => [
        'page' => (int) 1,
        'limit' => (int) 20,
        'maxLimit' => (int) 100,
        'whitelist' => [
            (int) 0 => 'limit',
            (int) 1 => 'sort',
            (int) 2 => 'page',
            (int) 3 => 'direction'
        ]
    ]

}
```

NOTE: The whitelist contains limit, sort, page and direction? And the limit is 20 and I don't even have a selection of 20?

**Result**
The sort is on the due_date and I need it on the task_name.

**Extra Info**
If I then click the sort on task_name the sort is on the task_name. All the sorts work just not on the initial load?

---

**Question**
How can I configure the pagination property so the sort is on the task_name from the initial load of the search method.

Thanks Z.

Comment: What exactly is that original code doing there in the first place? All these getter methods populating the pagination config, that looks like as if you're possibly injecting user input into the the paginator config?

Comment: @ndm Yes that is possible, the user can alter the page, sort, direction and limit in the URL and change the display based on those values. I didn't think this was an issue, these values are validated after they are set and before they are got to ensure that they are valid values but I haven't shown that in the post. I've edited the post to reflect that now.

Comment: I see, unless there's a specific reason for that, it probably shouldn't have been done that way, as the paginator sanitizes/validates the config user input (request data) on its own. The paginator config should normally just be used for configuring pagination defaults.

Comment: Fair enough, I didn't realise that. The reason I did validate it there was to negate a user injecting user input into the pagination property directly :-) If I'm correct you're saying that I do not need to do that validation anymore if I can access the paginator directly because this will invoke the $config where as you mention it sanitizes/validates the config user input anyway. Mind you there still valid values so they should still be ok to use in the config...

Comment: It's not about accessing the component directly, the paginator will validate/sanitize `limit`/`sort`/`page`/`direction` by default (after merging user request data and paginator config). That being said, specifying the default sorting in the pagination config works fine for me, the helper correctly "highlights" (adds the small arrow icon) as expected. You might need to boil this down to a more general, reproducible example.

Comment: btw, the `_config` in the debug dump is the components default configuration, not the config that you're passing to it! The latter is never stored in the object, it's processed on the fly and passed to the inner datasource paginator.

Comment: Thanks for having a look into it and confirming that the default config works for you. Not sure why my config does not but at least I know its not my config but something else whatever that might be? I'll have a closer look into it and hopefully post back with a reproducible example.

Comment: Could be many things. Maybe start with checking what sort key the paginator helper receives. In your template check `$this->Paginator->sortKey()`.

Comment: @ndm - will do - also just checked using $config in the index method just to see if it works and it does. So it's something to do with after I submit the form to search and render the index view from the search method.

Comment: @ndm - just checked debug($this->Paginator->sortKey()); in the tasks index view and it displays 'Tasks.due_date' and I need it to be 'Tasks.task_name'. Whichever sort is present in the index methods index view is still there after the form is submitted to search method.

Comment: If it works on index but not on search and the only thing different is that search renders the index view with $this->render('index'); then that suggests it may have something to do with $this->render('index');. I can create a new search view, not ideal but it may help to identify where the issue is occuring.

Comment: I tried creating a search view but it didn't make any difference. The sort is still not being applied?

Comment: Does the URL that your search form submits maybe already have a `sort` query parameter?

Comment: @ndm - No, the URL is - https://localhost/crm/tasks before I submit it. I then initialise the value I need with $this->request->getQuery('column'); and assign it to the sort setter in search which is the column name.

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas, there isn't really much I could do other than shooting in the dark. I'd suggest debugging the internals of `\Cake\Datasource\Paginator` to figure where exactly your passed `sort` value changes.

Comment: @ndm - Really appreciate the time the taken to help me out. I've just found a fix so I've written it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix is a bit costly and not ideal but it does work. I do a redirect on the initial load. Basically submit the form to search then redirect back to search. IE:

```
if ($this->request->getQuery('initial') === 'yes') {

    $redirect = $this->request->getQuery('redirect', [
        'action' => 'search',
         '?' => [
             'method' => 'search',
             'column' => $this->getColumn(),
             'input' => $this->getInput(),
             'page' => $this->getPage(),
             'sort' => $this->getSort(),
             'direction' => $this->getDirection(),
             'limit' => $this->getLimit(),
             'filter' => $this->getFilter(),
         ]
    ]);

    return $this->redirect($redirect);
    exit(0);

}

$config = $this->paginate = [
    'sortWhitelist' => [
       'Tasks.due_date',
       'Tasks.task_name',
       'Tasks.type',
       'Tasks.priority',
       'Tasks.related_to_name',
       'Contacts.first_name',
       'Contacts.last_name',
       'Accounts.account_name',
       'Tasks.task_desc'
     ],
     'page' => $this->getPage(),
     'sort' => $this->getSort(),
     'direction' => $this->getDirection(),
     'limit' => $this->getLimit()
 ];

 $tasks = $this->Paginator->paginate($query, $config);
 $this->set(compact('tasks'));
```

The sort is now on the task_name.

This negates the initial load problem and simulates usage after the page initially loads where I know the sorts work.