# Using the paginator directly and defining the sort on an associated column not working

Tags: cakephp, pagination

CakePHP Version: 4.0.1

**Introduction**

This problem follows on from another problem I had [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62086742/using-the-paginator-directly-is-not-recognising-the-configuration) where a not ideal solution was to redirect back to itself. Unfortunately the controller I was testing didn't have any associated columns so this new problem was not identified.

I referenced [this](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/controllers/components/pagination.html#using-the-paginatorcomponent-directly) in the cookbook.

Hopefully the below code will allow the problem to be reproduced.

---

**Contacts Table**

```
public function initialize(array $config): void
{
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->setTable('contacts');

    $this->belongsTo('Users', [
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);

    $this->belongsTo('Accounts', [
        'foreignKey' => 'account_id'
    ]);

}

// Custom Finder
public function findSuperuserAllContacts(Query $query, array $options): object
{
    $query
        ->where(['Contacts.status' => $options['status']])
        ->andWhere([
            'Users.client_id' => $options['client_id'],
            'Users.status' => 1
        ]);

    return $query;
}
```

**Contacts Controller**

```
public $paginate = [
    'sortWhitelist' => [
       'Contacts.first_name',
       'Contacts.last_name',
       'Accounts.account_name',
       'Users.first_name',
       'Users.last_name',
       'Contacts.primary_tel',
       'Contacts.mobile',
       'Contacts.email'
    ]
];

public function index() {

    $query = (object) $this->Contacts->find('superuserAllContacts', [
        'contain' => ['Users', 'Accounts'],
        'status' => 1,
        'client_id' => 1001
    ]);

    $page = '';
    $sort = 'Accounts.account_name';
    $direction = 'asc';

    $config = $this->paginate = [                
        'page' => $page,
        'sort' => $sort,
        'direction' => $direction,
        'limit' => 10
    ];        

    $contacts = $this->Paginator->paginate($query, $config);
    $this->set(compact('contacts'));

}
```

---

**What Happens**

The page displays a type error in the framework.

C:\xampp\htdocs\crm\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\View\Helper\PaginatorHelper.php

strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be a string, bool given

```
public function sortDir(?string $model = null, array $options = []): string
{
    $dir = null;

    if (empty($options)) {
        $options = $this->params($model);
    }

    if (isset($options['direction'])) {

        debug($options['direction']);  // THIS IS FALSE NOT asc or desc?

        $dir = strtolower($options['direction']);
    }

    if ($dir === 'desc') {
        return 'desc';
    }

    return 'asc';
}
```

---

**Stacktrace from error.log**

2020-06-01 10:33:20 Error: [TypeError] strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, bool given in C:\xampp\htdocs\crm\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\View\Helper\PaginatorHelper.php on line 264

Stack Trace:
- C:\xampp\htdocs\crm\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\View\Helper\PaginatorHelper.php:264
- C:\xampp\htdocs\crm\templates\Contacts\index.php:5
- C:\xampp\htdocs\crm\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\View\View.php:1164
- C:\xampp\htdocs\crm\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\View\View.php:1125
- C:\xampp\htdocs\crm\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\View\View.php:750
- C:\xampp\htdocs\crm\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Controller\Controller.php:691
- C:\xampp\htdocs\crm\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Controller\Controller.php:533
- C:\xampp\htdocs\crm\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Controller\ControllerFactory.php:79
- C:\xampp\htdocs\crm\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Http\BaseApplication.php:229
- C:\xampp\htdocs\crm\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Http\Runner.php:77
- C:\xampp\htdocs\crm\vendor\cakephp\authentication\src\Middleware\AuthenticationMiddleware.php:122
- C:\xampp\htdocs\crm\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Http\Runner.php:73
- C:\xampp\htdocs\crm\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\I18n\Middleware\LocaleSelectorMiddleware.php:70
- C:\xampp\htdocs\crm\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Http\Runner.php:73
- C:\xampp\htdocs\crm\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Http\Runner.php:77
- C:\xampp\htdocs\crm\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Http\Middleware\CsrfProtectionMiddleware.php:132
- C:\xampp\htdocs\crm\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Http\Runner.php:73
- C:\xampp\htdocs\crm\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Http\Runner.php:58
- C:\xampp\htdocs\crm\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Routing\Middleware\RoutingMiddleware.php:162
- C:\xampp\htdocs\crm\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Http\Runner.php:73
- C:\xampp\htdocs\crm\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Routing\Middleware\AssetMiddleware.php:68
- C:\xampp\htdocs\crm\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Http\Runner.php:73
- C:\xampp\htdocs\crm\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Error\Middleware\ErrorHandlerMiddleware.php:118
- C:\xampp\htdocs\crm\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Http\Runner.php:73
- C:\xampp\htdocs\crm\vendor\cakephp\debug_kit\src\Middleware\DebugKitMiddleware.php:60
- C:\xampp\htdocs\crm\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Http\Runner.php:73
- C:\xampp\htdocs\crm\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Http\Runner.php:58
- C:\xampp\htdocs\crm\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Http\Server.php:90
- C:\xampp\htdocs\crm\webroot\index.php:40

Request URL: /contacts
Referer URL: https://localhost/crm/welcome

---

**Question**

Why is a type error displayed instead of loading the index template with the sort on the account_name?

Thanks Z.

---

**EDIT**

I've just tried a fresh install with

composer self-update && composer create-project --prefer-dist cakephp/app:4.* crm

and baked users, contacts and accounts.

The new version is 4.0.8 and I added the code I have above in the new project but unfortunatley got exactly the same type error.

If the sort is on the same table, ie: Contacts.last_name the last name has the sort on it but if I change it to the associated table Accounts.account_name the type error is displayed.

Comment: What does your `Contacts\index.php` template do on line `5`?

Comment: Also note that you are not passing a sort field whitelist, which is required for using fields of associations.

Comment: @ndm - The `Contacts\index.php` template on line `5` is: debug($this->Paginator->sortDir());. Also could I ask you to expand a little on not passing the sort field whitelist as I thought I had. I have declared the sort fields whitelist in the public pagination property as shown in the post. Is that not passing the sort field whitelist?

Comment: It isn't, no, that property is used by the `Controller::paginate()` method, the paginator component doesn't pick it up on its own, but even if it would, you're completely overwriting it in your controller action.

Comment: @ndm - Ah - Well I'm not sure how to pass the sort field whitelist then. I referenced the 4 cookbook here: https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/controllers/components/pagination.html#control-which-fields-used-for-ordering and it doesn't state anything else. Would you mind letting me know how to do it or where I can find out how to do it.

Comment: Just set it in your `$config` variable that you're passing to the paginator component.

Comment: @ndm - Brills, thankyou. The cookbook could do with a tweak to reflect that though, would you agree? I don't mind initiating that, I'd have to sus out how to do it but I'm happy to help if I can.

Comment: I think it's already mentioned in the cookbook, more or less at least, it mentions that when using the component directly, the configuration passed to it should be structured the same as the `$paginate` property: **https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/controllers/components/pagination.html#using-the-paginatorcomponent-directly**

Comment: @ndm - I see what your saying, just about gets in on that sentence. :-) I'll edit this and the other post to reflect that so at least anyone looking in the future has this as a second reference.

Comment: @ndm - That's it, that's the answer. I've just added the whitelist to the config and tried an initial load on account_name and it all works perfectly, no type error. If you'd like to write that as an answer i'll give it a tick.

Comment: @ndm - I'll document this as an answer as I'd like to close this question with an answer for future readers. Hope you don't mind and thanks for your help as always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sort field whitelist must be passed in the config when using the paginator directly.

```
$config = $this->paginate = [
    'sortWhitelist' => [
        'Contacts.first_name',
        'Contacts.last_name',
        'Accounts.account_name',
        'Users.first_name',
        'Users.last_name',
        'Contacts.primary_tel',
        'Contacts.mobile',
        'Contacts.email'
    ],
    'page' => $page,
    'sort' => $sort,
    'direction' => $direction,
    'limit' => 10
];

$contacts = $this->Paginator->paginate($query, $config);
$this->set(compact('contacts'));
```

The sort is now displayed on the account_name.